# Ensure a csv file being uploaded to server is converted to utf-8

Tags: php, csv

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $
      return array('success'=> true);
 }
```

How can I utf-8 the content of the csv before moving the temporary file to its location. I am using php for this webapp. I have already got the utf encoding function, however, I don't know how to interfere in the upload process to encode the content of the file before it is uplaoded to the server.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do anything to the file until it is uploaded to the server, at least with PHP. You should put it in a tmp folder, mess with it, then move it.

Comment: it already is in a tmp folder, specified in the `$file['tmp_name']` path.

Comment: then you have to find where the tmp folder actually is (the info maybe in your php.ini or phpinfo()), and I think you can do the conversion to it there in the tmp folder. I may just be confused by your "interfere in the upload process" - once it is in the tmp folder, it is completely uploaded.

Comment: No, `file['tmp_name']` is the absolute path to the temporary file. However, access *might* be restricted by open_basedir so that only `move_uploaded_file` can access it. In this case you are right and it should be moved first. BTW, I'm not the OP ;)

Comment: ah, my fault, I thought you were.